# Is it possible to make a Tree View Select with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a collection to display even the child nodes like `<optgroup>` but optgroups can be selectable too. Data comes from API and I don't know how many child nodes can come. Is there any close directive or else in that field without any huge dependencies like kendo ui ? And I also know that select is a pain in a lot of browser.

Thanks

[image: Treeview Select]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe angular tree control will help you to achieve what you want. Here is the link for directive: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-tree-control